# WPF navigation and ViewModel instantiation with an MVVM Viewmodel first architecture

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, navigation

I have started a WPF application, and desire to follow an MVVM ViewModel first approach.

For navigation, I have seen many options:

- using a `ContentControl` and `UserControl`s (every page is a usercontrol)
- using a `ContentPresenter` and `ResourceDictionary`s (every page is a ResourceDictionary, or simply said : a DataTemplate)
- using a `Frame` with `Page`s

The third option is what seems to me is the 'Correct' approach, because `ContentControl` is for defining a Xaml control, and not a page.

I created a basic navigation service that holds a reference to the main window Frame.

My confusion now is at the level of how do I create my Views and ViewModels without breaking the MVVM pattern.

I thought about doing something like a ViewFactory:

```
ViewFactory.Register(typeof(FirstViewModel), typeof(FirstPage));
ViewFactory.Register(typeof(SecondViewModel), typeof(SecondPage));
ViewFactory.Register(typeof(ThirdViewModel), typeof(ThirdPage));
```

And then inside my NavigationService, navigate like (pseudo code):

```
public void Navigate(ViewModel viewModel) {
  Type viewType = ViewFactory.GetView(viewModel.GetType());
  Page page;
  page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
  // set the data context of the page with the passed 'viewModel'
  // put that view in the Frame like : _frame.NavigateTo(page)
}
```

but in this case, the viewModel is instantiated in the class that calls the navigate method (and that place would be another ViewModel) like:

```
//this code is defined inside my FirstViewModel
var vm = new SecondViewModel(args);
navigationService.Navigate(SecondViewModel);
```

- How do i get rid of this ViewModel instantiation ? I don't want my viewModel to be responsible for the creation of other viewModels, it doesn't sound right to me?
- Also this ViewFactory forces me to have a one viewModel per View

I can go and do something like this in the View xaml:

```
DataContext="{Binding FirstViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
```

But this is not ViewModel first anymore, and my view is strongly attached to a single ViewModel

**In short:**

- How do i navigate between different views in a ViewModel first approach using a Frame and Pages, without my viewModels 'hardcode'ingly instantiating each other?

*Any information that can clear this in my head would be appreciated.
feel free to propose another mechanism of navigation if not with Frames and Pages.*

Comment: If this seems to be long, you can read directly the "In short" question